# volatile keyword and RAII idiom (C++)

Tags: c++, volatile, raii

assuming to have a class to control concurrent access to a (critical) code block similar to this one:

```
class RAIIObj : public boost::noncopyable {
public:
    explicit RAIIObj( LockObj& Obj ) : LkObj( Obj ) { Obj.Acquire(); }
    ~RAIIObj() { try { Obj.Release(); } catch (...) {} }
private:
    LockObj& LkObj;
};
```

When using such piece of code, do I need to use volatile keyword in order 
not to see the code be optimized away?

For example, do I have to write

```
ALockingObj LockObj;

void AFunc() {
    RAIIObj LKGuard( LockObj );

    // do some MT stuff
}
```

or

```
ALockingObj LockObj;

void AFunc() {
    volatile RAIIObj LKGuard( LockObj );

    // do some MT stuff
}
```

in order to be sure that LKGuard always exists?

As LKGuard is a local variable that is not used at any point in the body of 
the function, could be optimized away if I do not use the volatile keyword?

Thanks

Comment: I think there are only one or two instances where a constructor/destructor pair can be optimized out, such as [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Otherwise I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no you dont need to declare it volatile. The compiler can see that instantiating lkobj does a whole bunch of stuff that cant be optimized out (as opposed to `int lkobj;` which clearly does nothing)

Answer (score -1):

While the answer provided by pm100 is indeed correct as far as the standard is concerned, I discovered that GCC 4.9 can optimize RAII types away (optimization flags: `-Os -flto`). This is the code I had that the optimizer was throwing away:

```
class MutexLocker
{
    chibios_rt::Mutex& mutex_;
public:
    MutexLocker(chibios_rt::Mutex& m) : mutex_(m)
    {
        mutex_.lock();
    }
    ~MutexLocker()
    {
        mutex_.unlock();
    }
};
```

Making the type volatile solved the problem:

```
namespace impl_
{
    class MutexLockerImpl
    {
        chibios_rt::Mutex& mutex_;
    public:
        MutexLockerImpl(chibios_rt::Mutex& m) : mutex_(m)
        {
            mutex_.lock();
        }
        ~MutexLockerImpl()
        {
            mutex_.unlock();
        }
    };
}
using MutexLocker = volatile impl_::MutexLockerImpl;
```

Therefore, despite the fact that the standard does not require that, I would suggest to explicitly declare RAII types volatile in order to account for aggressive optimization.

Comment: The compiler must have determined that `mutex_.lock()` and associated unlock had no effect on the rest of the code (i.e. the code would run the same with or without the lock).  If this is not actually true then it means the `lock()` function is not implemented properly and needs to be fixed - papering over the error in this one instance with `volatile` is not a good solution, the same bug may occur elsewhere that you don't realize.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a new question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that this is a GCC bug. This would not be surprising since version 4.9.3 (arm-none-eabi) that I'm using is actually extremely unstable. The implementation of the `lock()` method can be found here: https://github.com/ChibiOS/ChibiOS/blob/stable_3.0.x/os/various/cpp_wrappers/ch.cpp#L435-L438; which is just a proxy for this: https://github.com/ChibiOS/ChibiOS/blob/stable_3.0.x/os/rt/src/chmtx.c#L139-L236. (Yes this is an embedded system). I know that MCVE would help here, but it's somewhat complicated to provide one for an embedded application.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any memory fences in that lock implementation, perhaps a compiler-specific fence should be added to it